# Gradle auto-detect subprojects requiring build?

Tags: gradle

I was wondering if the multi-project configuration in gradle can be configured to auto-detect which sub-projects have had source changes and only build the relevant subprojects?

ie:  a parent project with 40 sub-projects,  1 sub-project has a source checkin, 3 of the other subprojects depend on the first sub project with the change.    Doing a build somehow only rebuilds the 4 of the 40 subprojects?

Comment: Isn't that what happens by default? Gradle will try to run the build task on all 40 sub-projects, then discover that they are up-to-date and skip the task.

Comment: As long as project dependencies are properly declared in settings.gradle, this is the default behavior. Do you have any dependency substitution or exclusion rules?